# solidity: issues calling function in implementation contract function from proxy contract

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I have one proxy contract and one implementation contact written in solidity. The steps I take is (I used Remix):

1. deploy the implementation contract, get the contract address.
2. go to compile details and found the initialize() function's bytecode, which is "8129fc1c": "initialize()"
3. put the implementation contact address into the `_LOGIC field`, put the my wallet address that used to deploy the proxy contract in the `_ADMIN field`, then put `0x8129fc1c` into the `_DATA` field. Then I deploy the proxy contract.
4. After both contracts are deployed. I go to the implementation contract, but put the proxy contract address into the `at address` field, so I can run the implementation contract via the proxy contract.

*There is one weird thing during the deployment: so the proxy contract deployment transaction is successful on the chain, but it is forever showing pending in the Remix console log.

Here is the problem:

1. many of the functions are greyed out when I do step 4. see screenshot below:
   [image]
2. whenever I try any function, it returns the `error: Fail with error 'TransparentUpgradeableProxy: admin cannot fallback to proxy target'`

**Question:**
Is there any steps I did is wrong? did I miss anything or ?

p.s. I do have an initialize func in the implementation contract, so when deploy the proxy contract, I put the `0x8129fc1c` into the _DATA field to initialize it. This is the initialize function:

```
function initialize() public initializer {
        __ERC20_init("MSBT", "SBT");
        __ERC20Burnable_init();
        __ERC20Snapshot_init();
        __AccessControl_init();
        __Pausable_init();

        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(OWNER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(BURNER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(SNAPSHOT_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setRoleAdmin(PAUSER_ROLE, OWNER_ROLE);
        _setRoleAdmin(BURNER_ROLE, OWNER_ROLE);
        _setRoleAdmin(MINTER_ROLE, OWNER_ROLE);
        _setRoleAdmin(SNAPSHOT_ROLE, OWNER_ROLE);

        cap = 1e27;
        _pause();
    }
```